# Symmetric vs Real Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Symmetric Matrix  A=Transpose(A)

Real Symmetric Matrix = Symmetric Matrix + All entries are Real Numbers

What extra things can we conclude when all the entries are Real and the matrix is Symmetric which are not true for Symmetric Matrix ?

Comment: Complex symmetric matrices have no particular properties, I think. The extension to complex numbers of symmetric matrices are hermitian matrices

Comment: Diagonal entries of symmetric matrix are purely real  if we take matrix with complex entries

Comment: I am looking for some advantage of Real Symmetric matrices over just Symmetric matrices, maybe in terms of diagonalizability, or something related to eigenvectors, orthonormality

Comment: symmetric matrices $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors